# How to show relative post difference category?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Currently, I can show relative post by category. Some category I am not so post, so when we click on the article it will show relative post, but post in that category I am not so update, so I want to user see other post from other category.
Please see image for clear.[Click here image for detail.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sh51.jpg)
I want to change the article on the YOU ALSO MAY LIKE to be the update one, at            least those are within 3 months from other category if that category no post.

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? How those section displayed there? using custom code? or wordpress plugin? Please update your questions with more details. Like the existing code and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will only work if your create custom taxonomy and custom post type.

i Hope this will help you.

```
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-1">
<ul class="product_list sub_cat list_view02">
    <?php
    $postterms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'Your_Custom_Taxonomy_Name');   // get post terms
    $parentId = $postterms[0]->parent; 
    $term_id = $parentId;
    $taxonomy_name = 'Your_Custom_Taxonomy_name';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'Your_Custom_Post_Type_Name',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'Your_Custom_Taxonomy_Name',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $term->slug,
    )
    )
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count=1;
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->ID) );
    ?>
        <li><img alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo $url?>" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <div><?php echo get_the_content(); ?> </div>
        <a class="view_more pull-right" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View Details</a>
        </li> 
    <?php endwhile;  
    }
    ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay Thank for wonderful answer, but if I don't use custom taxonomy and custom post type so how to solve this problem?

Comment: Because normally, we already have post so if we create custom taxonomy and custom post type we need to move all post to that too.but I will try it first. Thank you for you try the best to solving me. :)